# How to display a scroll bar for telerik radgrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am not able to enable scroll bar for telerik radgrid.

I have used `ClientSettings.Scrolling.AllowScroll=true`.

can any one help?

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/scrolling/scrolling/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set an explicit height to show the vertical scrollbar; without an explicit height, it won't show up.

Comment: Although all the examples I found specified height in px, I was able to specify height in em and it worked fine.

Comment: Yep, any height measurement will do.